# combination without repetition in R between vector elements

Tags: r, vector, combinations

I have a vector `x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)` and I'd like to write all combinations between one element and all others, eg. 12, 13, 14, 15 etc.., without having also 21.

```
comb <- expand.grid(rep(list(x), 2))
```

I'm using this command (founded here: [Combination without repetition in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339202/combination-without-repetition-in-r) ( the first answer gives the same) ) but I have repetition in the df I obtain. How I could avoid this? Thanks!

Comment: `combn(x, 2)`...?

Comment: @Sotos `combn(x,2)` gives me a matrix, I need a df with only 2 variables as in the output of `comb <- expand.grid(rep(list(x), 2))`

Comment: `as.data.frame(t(combn(x, 2)))`

Answer (score 0):

Solved with `as.data.frame(t(combn(x, 2)))`
Thanks!